# I can't get my kendoUI code to style

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, kendo-ui

I followed a simple kendo ui code sample, and I cannot get the theme to apply.  The drop down is the ordinary rectangular drop down with blue selected background color, rather than the kendo "default" theme, the orange background and rounded corners. I feel like I've combed every letter looking for mistakes.  Any ideas what I'm missing?  Do you get the same result on your machine with this code?

Thanks

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>

<title>test Kendo UI Web</title>

<link 
href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/styles/kendo.common.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/styles/kendo.default.min.css"     rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/js/jquery.min.js">     </script>

<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/js/kendo.ui.core.min.js">    </script>

</head>

<body>

<input id="datepicker" />

<br>

<br>

<select name="" data-role="dropdownlist">  
    <%--or.. id="dropdownlist">--%>

    <option value="">thing1</option>

      <option value="">thing2</option>

      <option value="">thing3</option>

       <option value="">thing4</option>

      <option value="">thing5</option>

</select>

 <script>

    (function () {
        kendo.bind(document.body);
    //or... $('#dropdownlist').kendoDropDownList();   
 });


$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
});


 </script>


 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors ? Watched the network traffic for the css requests and see what the return status code is ?

Comment: Here you go: [link](http://dojo.telerik.com/eWevO)

Comment: The code from the emulator worked great, not sure what's different yet, but I will figure that out.  Thank you!

Comment: in your example code the first javascript function will never run at least you have to put self execute brackets at the end if you want it to run ().